# ms word vba delete text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to ms Word VBA and have a editing question. 
In ms word my test is called test.doc.

I have 5 headings but the last 2 are: "$ > week1", and "$ > week2"
I would like to remove the last 2 headings by deleting them. 
I assumed that I just find $ which I can do but I don't know how to get the rest of the text to delete them. The last 2 headings are separated by a tab.

Also in the last 2 columns I have monetary values like $45 or $30
I would like to search and find the $ and get rid of the both the $ and the numbers after it.

I have some code:

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim myWord As Range
For Each myWord In ActiveDocument.Words
     myWord.Select
     doEvents
Next
End Sub
```

I think I need a way to loop thru the whole file then read a word at a time and search for the "$".
Or since the whole file is tab delimited just count the tabs then delete the last 2 columns of data by somehow going to the end of the line and do a select and delete?
I would appreciate any code that might help.

Comment: try with `find and replace` using wildcards. [THIS LINK](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm) will be good to start with.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Actually I solved it by going to the $ backing up one char and then deleting the remainder of the text. Solved.